# How to select three days using datepicker in vue

Tags: vue.js, vcalendar

Im using VCalendar - datepicker and I want to highlight days which are in my array: ['2022-02-01', '2022-02-08', '2022-02-15'], I cant find this in documentation, there is only single date or range of dates, but not alone dates like in my array, which are all tuesdays for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually VCalendar has documentation to achieve multiple date selection
https://vcalendar.io/examples/datepickers.html#multiple-dates

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    dates: ['2022-02-01', '2022-02-08', '2022-02-15']
  }),
  
  computed: {
    attributes() {
      return this.dates.map(date => ({
        highlight: true,
        dates: date,
      }));
        }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/v-calendar@2.4.0/lib/v-calendar.umd.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-calendar :attributes="attributes" />
</div>
```

Comment: and if I only want those days to be highlighted from the start so user sees those three days, but cant choose anything, I want it to be only visual thing, should I use something else or datepicker is okay for that? also I dont know how to achieve that, nothing works for me

Comment: Just remove `@dayclick="onDayClick"` and fill dates like on example